# php dom only edit parent element and not child elements

Tags: php, dom, element

I am trying to edit nodevalue of only the parent element (eg hold1) and not the child elements. The below code successfully lets me edit the child elements but when i edit the parent element, it removes the child elements completely. Please help.

```
$file = 'home/aa.php';
$doc = new DOMdocument();
$doc = loadHTMLFile($file);
$element = $doc->getElementById('hold1');
$element->nodeValue= "THIS IS SPARTA";
$myfile = fopen($file,'w+'); // i have tried c, c+, a+, r+ , none helps
$html = fwrite($myfile,$doc->saveHTML());

//aa.php
<div id = "hold1"> 
<div id = "hold2"> Tom is Cruise </div>
<div id = "hold3"> Ben Stiller parody </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `$doc->saveHTML()`? Or where did you get `$dom`? Does it produce the HTML you expect?

Comment: @Rudie , yep - doc, i'll correct it

Comment: [This](http://3v4l.org/6YAPg) any useful?

Comment: Well, div 2 and 3 are part of the div 1, so when you call nodeValue you get them. You could try to append. Have you tried $element->nodeValue .= "this is sparta"; ?

Comment: @Arthur Samarcos , that was a nice idea, it dint resolve it, but good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the nodeValue you're setting the entirely body of the element. You need to be explicit where you want the new text node to be. Example:

```
$element = $doc->getElementById('hold1');
$element->insertBefore($doc->createTextNode("THIS IS SPARTA"), $element->firstChild);
```

puts it in at the beginning

```
<div id="hold1">THIS IS SPARTA
<div id="hold2"> Tom is Cruise </div>
<div id="hold3"> Ben Stiller parody </div>
</div>
```